# System.currenttimemillis выводит некорректно часы

Tags: java, дата

```
long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
long second = seconds%60;
long minute = seconds/60%60;
long hour = seconds/3600%24;
textView.setText(hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
```

На компьютере 20.00, на выходе будет:

> 15:0:0

Проблема в том, что часы отстают на 5 часов. Что я не так делаю? Через календарь не надо, мне именно с этим надо разобраться. Я так понял это из - за часового пояса?

Comment: А вы вообще знаете, что возвращает `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть в описание метода то увидим следующее:

> - @return  the difference, measured in milliseconds, between
> - the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

т.е. `timestamp` приходит в часовом поясе [UTC+0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%C2%B10:00), из за этого и получается расхождения с местным временем

Comment: Всё-таки, `currentTimeMillis` возвращает количество миллисекунд, это просто число, оно не имеет часового пояса. Просто момент времени, когда начался отсчёт этого числа, принято выражать в UTC. Легко показать, что это также количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 03:00:00 UTC+3, но это не заставит `currentTimeMillis` "быть" в часовом поясе UTC+3.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Да, конечно, число не может быть в каком то часовом поясе.